Show dd/mm/yy in django
I have a input type Date field like below.
# forms.py
widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }   

I am using below code in HTML Template.
<label class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
{{ form.date_of_birth }}  

I am getting mm/dd/yy format but I would like to get dd/mm/yy format.
I am getting this output.


Does this answer your question? Django date format 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Thanks @anupsabraham. No that is not answer of my question. I am getting output like this.  https://i.sstatic.net/gwG9uaXI.png

You can just pass the format like this i guess:
widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(format="%d-%m-%Y", attrs={'type': 'date'})
        } 


Thanks @Muhammad Waqar Anwar. I am getting output like this. https://i.sstatic.net/gwG9uaXI.png

you are getting the same issue after trying my solution?

Thanks @Muhammad Waqar Anwar. Yes, I am getting same issue after trying your solution.
